# Can not add "Symbolic Breakpoint" for "-[NSTextField setStringValue:]"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, breakpoints

I'm trying to add "Symbolic Breakpoint" for "-[NSTextField setStringValue:]".

At first sight it is a task similar to described on [WWDC 2018](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/412/?time=655)

But it doesn't trigger at all in my case.

So I decided to google at found [an article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/xcode-breakpoint-wizardry/). And added another breakpoint - "-[NSViewController viewDidLoad]" and it works well. Also it is shown as a group, but my breakpoint doesn't. And this(viewDidLoad) breakpoint triggers, but my breakpoint(setStringValue:) doesn't.

[image]

I found a lot of advices to edit project settings to make symbolic breakpoints work, But I tried, and I think it's not my case because the other breakpoint triggers. And my breakpoint should be also displayed as a group(with a disclosure triangle at the left sight. and have at least one subitem).

PS

Any way. Thank for attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield?language=objc) `setStringValue:` is implemented by `NSControl`.

Try creating a symbolic breakpoint like this:

`-[NSControl setStringValue:]`

Comment: Thanks, I missed it.